# .htaccess to redirect homepage to "about" page for desktop users

Tags: .htaccess, mobile, redirect, desktop, user-agent

On a wordpress website, we're using wptouch pro plugin to provide a mobile version of the website (so no separate mobile website).
We get mobile traffic through a QR code pointing to our frontpage (e.g. www.example.net). However, we'd like desktop users to be redirected to www.example.net/about/ page.
Is it possible to do this through the use of .htaccess or another way would be better?

For example, adding :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /about/ [R=301,L]
```

before Wordpress .htaccess data

redirects all traffic from www.example.net to www.example.net/about/

Is it possible to put a condition that this redirect should only visitor is not within specified (mobile) user agents?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(MSIE.*Windows\ NT|Lynx|Safari|Opera|Firefox|Konqueror) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ about/ [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @anubhava, your post was very helpful!
We had to comment out

   # Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

as server was giving a 500 error, and also added

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(^.*(Opera\ Mini|SymbianOS|Mobile)) [NC]
to the first RewriteCond

and achieved redirection of Desktop visitors only, while keeping mobile visitors to access the homepage.

Thanks again!